# Given that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, which of the following is a true statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, proof-writing

> Given that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, which of the following is a true statement
>
> a) $~\forall y~(\exists x:\lvert x\rvert=y)$
>
> b) $~\forall y~(\exists x:\lvert x\rvert<y)$
>
> c) $~\forall y~(\exists x:\lvert x\rvert>y)$
>
> d) $~\forall y~(\exists x:\lvert x\rvert=-y)$

The answer is c) but for all $y$ within real numbers shouldn't have any correlation with $x$ for all $y$. Such as the absolute value of $x$ should not always return a value greater than $y$ but will when $y < 0$. What is incorrect with this train of thought?

Comment: For any given $y$, I can choose $x$ such that $|x|$ is bigger than $y$. For instance, take $x=y+1$. That is essentially what the answer boils down to.

Comment: All it is saying is *there exists* a $x$ such that $|x|>y$. It is *not* stating that for a given $x$ and $y$, we have $|x|>y$. The others don't hold due to the potential for $y$ (or $-y$) to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite understand about the use of term "correlation".

For every $y$, the $x$ chosen can be dependent on $y$. In particular, we can choose $x=|y|+1$. Regardless of the sign of $y$, once we fix the $y$, this choice of $x$ would  satisfy the inequality.

The counterexamples for the rest can be constructed using the fact that absolute value is nonnegative.